# How to save image taken by phone to local folder in Windows Phone 8.1

Tags: c#, image, stream, windows-phone-8.1

Is there a way I can get the image as Stream and then store it locally to upload it to server?

So far I found the code below which lets me load the image to an image view , but how do I create a stream from the image source to pass it to SaveToLocalFolderAsync method?

```
    private async void viewActivated(CoreApplicationView sender, IActivatedEventArgs args1)
    {

        FileOpenPickerContinuationEventArgs args = args1 as FileOpenPickerContinuationEventArgs;

        if (args != null)
        {
            if (args.Files.Count == 0) return;
            view.Activated -= viewActivated;
            StorageFile storageFile = args.Files[0];
            var stream = await storageFile.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read);
            var bitmapImage = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage();
            await bitmapImage.SetSourceAsync(stream);
            var decoder = await Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(stream);
            imgCover.Source = bitmapImage;



            //save the image in local folder

            //SaveToLocalFolderAsync(stream, "Test.jpg");

        }
    }




  public async Task SaveToLocalFolderAsync(Stream file, string fileName)
    {
        StorageFolder localFolder = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
        StorageFile storageFile = await localFolder.CreateFileAsync(fileName, CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting);
        using (Stream outputStream = await storageFile.OpenStreamForWriteAsync())
        {
            await file.CopyToAsync(outputStream);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to copy like this: `await args.Files[0],CopyToAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder, "test.jpg");`?